# Detached garage with a 3-wire feeder

Tags: grounding-and-bonding

This house is being sold, a home inspection has noted that the neutral and branch circuit ground wires are landed on the same bar in the sub panel at the detached garage,it is feed with 3 wires from the main. This house was built in the 80's. My question is what is the fix? Is there an exception that will allow this to be left as is? Am I required to separate the existing connections, and add a 4th wire back to the main panel?

Comment: Is this feeder overhead, direct buried, or in a conduit?

Comment: The original subpanel installation, did they pull a permit?

Comment: The feeder from the house is ran in 3-wire AL with no conduit underground.

Comment: The feeder is 3-wire AL underground no conduit. No permit, this house is built in the county (no permit, or inspection required.)

Comment: Where are those two wires hooked up to in the main panel.

Comment: two wire to a 100a breaker and one wire to the neutral bar

Comment: Is digging up and replacing this feeder an option? Also, what loads does the garage have at it?